How to Use Pessimistic Locking with a Versioned Entity in JPA Without Conflicts
I have a usecase where a there is a pool_account table which track merchant balance, and any credit for merchant balance is incremented and a audit table entry is created for amount, opening balance, closing balance to keep track of it.
Due to multiple credit orders I wanted to use pessimistic write to acquire lock and noone should able to read it. But the problem is this is code is common core_banking library and pool_account table has version column with @version annotation to use optimisitc locking.
below is library code

@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "pool_account")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public final class PoolAccount implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private long accountId;

    @Column(name = "account_number")
    private String accountNumber;

    @Column(name = "balance")
    private BigInteger balance;

    @Column(name = "version")
    @Version
    private long version;
}


public interface PoolAccountRepository extends JpaRepository<PoolAccount, Long> {
    PoolAccount getPoolAccountByAccountNumber(String accountNumber);

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query("SELECT da FROM PoolAccount da WHERE da.accountNumber = :accountNumber")
    PoolAccount getPoolAccountByAccountNumberForUpdate(@Param("accountNumber") String accountNumber);
}

@Transactional(
        isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED,
        rollbackFor = {Exception.class, RuntimeException.class},
        propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
void creditMerchantAccount(){
    PoolAccount poolAccount = poolAccountRepository.getPoolAccountByAccountNumberForUpdate("123");
    // increase balance
    poolAccountRepository.save(poolAccount);


    // create new txn_audit table row with amount, starting balance, closing balance to track opening and closing balance for each txn
}



below is my service code

@Transactional(
        isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED,
        rollbackFor = {Exception.class, RuntimeException.class},
        propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
void creditMerchantOrder(){
    saveMerchantOrder(); // save in order table with amount
    creditMerchantAccount() // increase the merchant account balance
}


so when I try to fetch poolaccount record by pessimistic write I am getting error Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) when having transcxtion inside transaction. error is coming on line PoolAccount poolAccount = poolAccountRepository.getPoolAccountByAccountNumberForUpdate("123");
If I remove @transactional annotation from my service creditMerchantOrder() function I don't get above error.
I have @Transactional in my creditMerchantOrder service method because, if lib.creditMerchantAccount() fails, I need the changes made by saveMerchantOrder() to be rolled back as well. This ensures that no partial data is left in the database if an error occurs.
How can I use Pessismistic locking while keep @version column for other to use optimistic locking for other pool_account rows. ( I am not mixing optimisic and pessimistic for same row)`
